# How to receive ArrayBuffer in .Net Controller?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net, react-native

i am trying to send an image from react native to .Net webApi,
i convert the base64 of the image to binary as follows :

```
    let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(value.length * 2);
  let view = new Uint16Array(buffer);

  for (let i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
    view[i] = value.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  return buffer;
```

then send it to the API, but i am getting this ERROR

Request was short circuited at action filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ModelStateInvalidFilter'

my model is :

```
   public partial class DPerson
{
    public Person person { get; set; } = new Person();
    public byte[]? pImage { get; set; }
}
```

it seems like the modelState is not valid, and can't configure the ArrayBuffer as byte array,

The whole Idea is to do all the convertions in the front and save calculations in the BACK

BTW it worked when i changed the types in both FRONT and BACK to string!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you keep the byte array in base64, so you can send pImage as a string instead of an array of bytes ?

If you want to get the byte array back on server side, take a look at the [Encoding class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=net-7.0).

Comment: it will work, i am trying to store the image in SQL and it's better to save it as binary. Now i am trying to find equivalent to these Encoding classes in Js, so the BACKEND won't have a load to DO!!! is it even possible ?!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).